# Cwd::abs_path() returns undef

Tags: perl, filesystems

I have an issue with using `abs_path()`. I give this function a valid path, but I get `undef` as a return value. The path is read from the command line using the following code.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Cwd qw();

print scalar @ARGV;
print "\n";

print "$ARGV[0]\n";
print "$ARGV[1]\n";
print "$ARGV[2]\n";
my $val = $ARGV[2];
print "$val\n";
my $result = "";
$result = Cwd::abs_path($val);
print "$result\n";
```

The perl script is executed as follows:

```
perl pl_test.pl -results_dir = /home/user123/
```

I get the following result:

```
3
-results_dir
=
/home/user123/
/home/user123/
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at pl_test.pl line 16.
```

I have verified using the debugger that the issue is that $result gets `undef` as return value from `Cwd::abs_path($val);`. I don't understand why this happens

One of the comments prompted me to do some further testing. What I found is that there is a dependency on a trailing slash, in the following manner:

1. if the directory does not exist: works without a trailing slash, returns `undef` with a trailing slash.
2. if the directory is a sub directory of a directory that does not exist, always returns `undef`
3. if the directory exists, will work in both cases, with or without a trailing slash

Comment: Does the directory `/home/user123` exists?

Comment: It does not. Is `undef` the correct return value in this case?

Comment: It should work without the trailing slash.

Comment: @sidyll: not quite. if the directory itself does not exist, it will work without the trailing slash, but will not work with it. If the directory is a sub directory of a directory that does not exist, it will not work with or without a slash. if the directory actually exists, it will work both with and without a trailing slash

Comment: @sidyll Curiously, I also get it to behave differently w/ or w/o the trailing slash. However, the module works with the filesystem and for all I know it doesn't make sense using it on non-existing paths. (In my mind the dependence on the slash only underscores this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Cwd` does use the filesystem so you shouldn't ask it to work with non-existent paths.

I've confirmed the observation that it does in fact give me back a path with a non-existent directory if it is in the directory which does exist (and has no trailing slash!), otherwise not. However, this doesn't mean much as the module's purpose is to work with existing paths.

To work with file names in general, for which files need not exist, use the core [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html)

```
perl -MCwd=abs_path -MFile::Spec=rel2abs -wE'
    say abs_path(".");
    say abs_path("./no/such") // "undef";
    say File::Spec->rel2abs("./no/such")
'
```

This prints

```
/home/my-user-name
undef
/home/my-user-name/no/such
```

The trailing slashes don't affect (meaningful) operations of either modules.

Another useful tool is [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#absolute), with many methods for a variety of work with existing and non-existing paths.

Comment: To add, Cwd::abs_path also has other non-portable behavior when given nonexistent paths. For instance on Windows it sometimes just dies. On IRC some said its behavior additionally differs between Linux, BSD and OS X, and it's perhaps due to the underlying `realpath` system call.

Answer (score -1):

realpath of perl don't answer well for patch end with "/", like "/home/"

which realpath of bash answer well,

so if u want to call realpath in perl, pay attention to trim last "/" first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).